# If $A$ and $B$ are compact sets in $M$, show that $A\cap B$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

If $A$ and $B$ are compact sets in $M$, show that $A\cap B$ is compact.

Could someone please check my proof for this problem? My working definition of "compact" is

> $P$ is compact iff every sequence in $P$ has a subsequence that
>   converges to a point in $P$.

**My attempt:**

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $A\cap B$.

$x_n\in A\cap B$

$\implies x_n\in A$ and $x_n\in B$

So, $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $A$. Since $A$ is compact, $(x_n)$ has a subsequence $(x_{n_i})$ that converges to a point $y\in A$.

$(x_n)$ is a sequence in $B$. Since $B$ is compact, $(x_n)$ has a subsequence $(x_{m_i})$ that converges to a point $z\in B$.

This is where I'm stuck. How do I proceed? I considered taking the common terms of the 2 subsequences but there need not be any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the space involved are Hausdorff since you use subsequences. The idea is to consider $x_{n_i}$as a subsequence of $B$ since $x_{n_i}$ is also in $B$ which  has a subsequence  $x_{n_{i_j}}$ which converges and the limit is also $y$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "subsequence of $B$".

Comment: $x_{n_i}\in B$ this is what I mean, you can extract from $(x_{n_i}\in B)$ a subsequence which converges.

Comment: The idea is to extract a subsequence from the subsequence that you have already extracted.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show that every open cover of $A\cap B$ has a finite sub-cover.

Take an open cover of $A\cap B$ and augment it with the complement of $A\cap B$

Note that this complement is open and it covers everything which in not in $A\cap B$

This  augmented covering  will cover both $A$ and $B$

Thus it has a finite sub-cover for $A$ and  a finite sub-cover for $B$

The union of these two covering is a finite open covering for $A\cap B $

Thus $A\cap B $ is compact.

Comment: This seems to work for $A \cup B$ as well, unless I am missing something replacing $A \cap B$ with $A \cup B$ everywhere

Comment: I appreciate your help but I wanted to use the definition of "compact" that I quoted.

Comment: @AndresMejia Yes it should work for $A \cup B$ as well.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the comment. Consider it as another attempt.

Comment: @Thomas  since $A \cap B \subset A,B$, take any sequence $a_n$ in $A$ and find a subsequence $a_{n_i}$ that works. Then regard $a_{n_i}$ as a subsequence in $B$ and a further subsequence. These have the same limit. The approach in this answer is worth being familiar with imo

Answer (score 0):

You take the sequence $(x_n) \subset A \cap B$, then $(x_n) \subset A$, so there exists $(x_{n_i})$ subsequence that converges to a $y \in A$

Then $(x_{n_i}) \subset A \cap B$, so it has a subsequence $(x_{n_{i_j}}) \subset B$ that conveges a point $z \in B$

Then $y = z$

Sorry for my bad english